# How to find the angle bisectors of 2 lines

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

I tried gooogling how to do it but there were none that could relate to the problem I have.

Find the angle bisectors of the lines:
$$g: r=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    5 \\
    -9 \\
    \end{pmatrix}+u  \begin{pmatrix}
    8 \\
    4 \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$f: r=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 \\
    5 \\
    -9 \\
    \end{pmatrix}+v  \begin{pmatrix}
    12 \\
    4 \\
    3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Could someone give me an idea on how to start solving this question?
I know that in order to determine the direction of the angle bisectors of the lines need to have the same length. So if

$u$ or $v$ =$0$
then they would have the same length no? But idk how to go from there.

Comment: Have you learned the "parallelogram rule" of vector addition?  If those vectors were of equal length, their sum would bisect the angle between them.  Scale your vectors accordingly.

Comment: yeah we learned that. But can I use that rule here? @Doug M

Comment: Note:  I wasn't able to place this where it belong, since I deleted my answer.I deleted the answer I gave.  I misunderstood the question and others have the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|(8,4,1)\| = \sqrt{64+16+1} = 9\\
\|(12,4,3)\| = \sqrt{144+16+9} = 13$

If we scale our vectors by $\frac {1}9,\frac {1}{13}$ respectively we will have two unit vectors pointing in different directions.  When we sum them, the sum will bisect the angle between them.

$r = \pmatrix{2\\5\\-9} + s\left(\frac 19 \pmatrix{8\\4\\1} + \frac {1}{13}\pmatrix{12\\4\\3}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

First normalise the two directing vectors. A directing vector of the angle bisectors of the two lines are simply the sum and the difference of the two normalised directing vectors, by a property of rhombuses.

Comment: Do you mean making g:r = f:r and then finding out what U and V are?